# Java Code to extend user Session in Websphere Portal

Tags: java, session, websphere-8

I am having a requirement where we show the user who is idle for 30 minutes to get a warning. I have the Javascript code ready wherein the user will get the pop-up asking him for 5 minutes ( counter is present) if he wants to extend the session or not. 
If he chooses Yes, then we need to extend the session by another 30 minutes( or the given time interval in the session) and so on. This process continues and the user can carry on with their work until he closes the window.

Can you tell me how I can , via my Java code, extend the session like this? I am interested in the server side code which I need to write. An example of the above scenario would be great to have.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Environment:- Websphere Portal 8.x , JDK 1.7

Comment: Hi Gas, thanks for the comments. We want to automatically extend it too and not pester the user about it. However, are you saying that if I make any AJAX call to any servlet, then it will automatically extend the session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any request that you will make from that browser to the Java code from your application e.g. portlet, servlet, that will access session will automatically extend it.

Comment: Can you give me the e.g. here? You are basically telling me that if I make simple Ajax call to a servlet that I have in my code, then this call will automatically extend the session?

Comment: @jbdundas Yes, ajax call is a good example. However you have to be aware about LTPA timeout, which is by default 120 minutes, and it is not extendable (relogin required), so if you plan longer sessions, you would need to change that default.

Comment: HI Gas, I tried this but it still does not work. It shows that the session is extended but the portlets on the UI are still not able to perform the AJAX calls. Any ideas why?

Comment: @jbdundas What do you mean by "UI not able to perform AJAX"?

Comment: We have multiple portlets on our page. when we extend the session via an Ajax call from the theme, it is not extending the session for these portlets. The AJAX actions on these portlets do not seem to work. So it seems that we need to set the session for each of the portlets for it to work. Am I correct? Any other way of handling this as the above approach is not working.

Comment: We have to disable portlet session timeouts and then the server container timeout had to be set to 30 minutes. This helped portlets to be always active while the session of the container controls the overall timeout.Thanks for the help.